# How to display the cross next to the text in this SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a SVG file with a lot of element like this one, I want to add a cross next the title of each one. I founded here https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/jEgvpo how to add a cross but I can't display it next to the title.
How can I display it next to the title?
I know it's something with the `d="..."` but I can't specify the value statically

```css
.close-x {
  stroke: black;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 5;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" contentscripttype="application/ecmascript" contentstyletype="text/css" height="555px" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="width:1181px;height:555px;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1181 555" width="1181px" zoomAndPan="magnify"><defs><filter height="300%" id="f491e1k" width="300%" x="-1" y="-1"><feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" stdDeviation="2.0"></feGaussianBlur><feColorMatrix in="blurOut" result="blurOut2" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 .4 0"></feColorMatrix><feOffset dx="4.0" dy="4.0" in="blurOut2" result="blurOut3"></feOffset><feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut3" mode="normal"></feBlend></filter></defs>
<g>
<!--entity cadvisor-->
<rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#f491e1k)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="97" x="133.675" y="8"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="210.675" y="13"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="208.675" y="15"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="208.675" y="19"></rect>
<text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="57" x="148.675" y="41.3027">cadvisor</text>
<path class="close-x" d="M 10,10 L 30,30 M 30,10 L 10,30" />

<!--entity cadvisor2-->
<rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#f491e1k)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="104" x="433.175" y="377"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="517.175" y="382"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="515.175" y="384"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="515.175" y="388"></rect>
<text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="64" x="448.175" y="410.3027">cadvisor2</text>
<path class="close-x" d="M 10,10 L 30,30 M 30,10 L 10,30" />

</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: What title are you talking about?

Comment: @Alexander I'm talking about `cadvisor` and `cadvisor2`  the `<text>` tag

Comment: Is the [use](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement) element what you need?

Comment: @Alexander yes here it's an example of a real element of my big svg, so if I can add the cross next to the title of one `<!--entity title -->` I will be able to adapt my code. One constraint is that all these elements are created dynamically, so I'll need to add the cross after the creation of the svg.

Comment: @Alexander if it seems to hard to do I have an other solution. (and I'm able to do it), when I click on a title, I open a box with an option to delete the container. So just tell me, you think it's easier to open the box with the delete option ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define the cross in `<defs>` section and reuse it in body with `<use>` element. To set new position of the cross use `x` and `y` attribytes. See snippet below.

```css
.close-x {
  stroke: black;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 5;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" contentscripttype="application/ecmascript" contentstyletype="text/css" height="555px" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="width:1181px;height:555px;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1181 555" width="1181px" zoomAndPan="magnify">
<defs><filter height="300%" id="f491e1k" width="300%" x="-1" y="-1"><feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" stdDeviation="2.0"></feGaussianBlur><feColorMatrix in="blurOut" result="blurOut2" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 .4 0"></feColorMatrix><feOffset dx="4.0" dy="4.0" in="blurOut2" result="blurOut3"></feOffset><feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut3" mode="normal"></feBlend></filter>
<path id="mycross" class="close-x" d="M 0,0 L 20,20 M 20,0 L 0,20" />
</defs>
<g>
<!--entity cadvisor-->
<rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#f491e1k)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="97" x="133.675" y="8"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="210.675" y="13"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="208.675" y="15"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="208.675" y="19"></rect>
<text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="57" x="148.675" y="41.3027">cadvisor</text>
<use xlink:href="#mycross" x="205" y="30"/>

<!--entity cadvisor2-->
<rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#f491e1k)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="104" x="433.175" y="377"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="517.175" y="382"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="515.175" y="384"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="515.175" y="388"></rect>
<text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="64" x="448.175" y="410.3027">cadvisor2</text>
<use xlink:href="#mycross" x="515" y="400"/>

</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Jerome, ready. You can create the group only one in `<defs>` and  duplicates them by `<use>`. `x` and `y` values of this helps you to set need position.

Answer (score 2):

USE THIS PATH

**1st cardover**

`<path class="close-x" d="M 140,12 L 150,25 M 150,12 L 140,25"></path>`

**2nd cardover**

`<path class="close-x" d="M 440,380 L 450,392 M 450,380 L 440,392"></path>`

```
.close-x {
  stroke: black;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

**SNIPPET**

```css
.close-x {
  stroke: black;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" contentscripttype="application/ecmascript" contentstyletype="text/css" height="555px" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="width:1181px;height:555px;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1181 555" width="1181px" zoomAndPan="magnify"><defs><filter height="300%" id="f491e1k" width="300%" x="-1" y="-1"><feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" stdDeviation="2.0"></feGaussianBlur><feColorMatrix in="blurOut" result="blurOut2" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 .4 0"></feColorMatrix><feOffset dx="4.0" dy="4.0" in="blurOut2" result="blurOut3"></feOffset><feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut3" mode="normal"></feBlend></filter></defs>
<g>
<!--entity cadvisor-->
<rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#f491e1k)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="97" x="133.675" y="8"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="210.675" y="13"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="208.675" y="15"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="208.675" y="19"></rect>
<text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="57" x="148.675" y="41.3027">cadvisor</text>
<path class="close-x" d="M 140,12 L 150,25 M 150,12 L 140,25"></path>

<!--entity cadvisor2-->
<rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#f491e1k)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="104" x="433.175" y="377"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="517.175" y="382"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="515.175" y="384"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="515.175" y="388"></rect>
<text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="64" x="448.175" y="410.3027">cadvisor2</text>
<path class="close-x" d="M 440,380 L 450,392 M 450,380 L 440,392"></path>

</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for the input I appreciate , I'll use the solution of @Alexander.